# How do I register a button click to call a service function that returns results?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a **service** that processes data and returns values, I have a button that is registered to my scope.

Is there a way to register the button to directly call the service function and collect results?

```
// html
<button ng-click="submit()"></button>

// controller
$scope.submit = MyService.submit(data); // How do I get the returned values?

// service
var returnValue = "SomeValue";
return returnValue;
```

Solution:

```
// controller
$scope.submit = function()
{
   var results = MyService.submit(data);
}
```

Comment: No. Thats why we have controllers.

Comment: I just realized I could make a function for submit and call the service in there. Duh moment.

Comment: You mean a simple JavaScript function? Breaking the purpose of Angular

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/QPCMxcmefIzYTTz8RBTm?p=preview) plunker.

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="getResults();">Get Results</button>
```

**JS**

```
(function(angular) {
  angular.
  module('myServiceModule', []).
  controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'result', function($scope, result) {
    $scope.getResults = function() {
      alert(result);
    };
  }]).
  factory('result', function() {
    var returnValue = "SomeValue";
    return returnValue;
  });
})(window.angular);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$scope.submit = MyService.submit(function(data){
  var returnValue =data;
}); // How do I get the returned values?
```

get MyServise as a promise